# SmsManager displays alert prior to send SMS

Tags: android, alert, smsmanager

I am really confused regarding one issue. Precisely, I'm sending a SMS to a number (fetched from web-service) each time application is opened. Code Snippet is as :

```
    private void sendSMSToDevices() {
        try {
            String SENT = "SentSMSActivity";
        String DELIVERED = "ReceivedSMSActivity";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        if (flagFirstTime) {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone_one, null, message_one, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        } else {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone_two, null, message_two, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

uses permissions in Manifest file are as ::

**android.permission.SEND_SMS**

**android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE**

**android.permission.INTERNET**

**android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED**

Each time I open the app, it dispays an alert prior to send SMS saying "(my_App_Name) would like to send a message to (phone_nember)"

I never put any alert inside my code. Why is it happening like this? Please Help.